# Find the limit of a definite integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

A definite integral is defined as
$$I(v,\theta)=\int_0^{\pi} e^{v[\cos(\theta-\phi)-1]}\sqrt{\dfrac{v \sin\phi}{\sin\theta}}d\phi$$

My question is how to show that 
$$\lim_{v\to \infty} I(v, \theta)=\sqrt{2\pi}$$
for any given $\theta \in (0, \pi)$.

My understanding is like this. Since $v$ goes to infinity, the main contribution of the integral comes from those $\phi$ values which are close to $\theta$ (because of the exponential term). I tried the Taylor expansion of $\phi$ around $\theta$, for example,
\begin{align*}
 \cos (\theta -\phi) &\approx 1-\dfrac{(\theta-\phi)^2}{2!} + \dfrac{(\theta-\phi)^4}{4!} + \cdots \\
\sin \phi & \approx \sin \theta + \cos\theta(\phi-\theta) - \dfrac{\sin \theta}{2}(\phi-\theta)^2 + \cdots
\end{align*}
but still can't go far. I don't know if I am on the right track. Please help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem? If so, making the substitution $\phi' = \sqrt{v}(\phi - \theta)$ and letting $v\rightarrow\infty$ will probably do it. Even if you can't use that theorem, the substitution may be helpful.